# ESXi Connection issue

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-server

We have a server currently running VMware ESXi. The VMSphere client is having some issues connecting; giving the "Can not establish a secure connection" when clicking on Console as well as both lag issues when trying to perform any task such as clicking on tabs and windows. On top of this we are getting "Error connecting: A secure connection to the host could not be established. Try again?" every few moments.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Is it on our side or on the server hosting side? Our server host is "Joe's Data Center" so if anyone has any idea on their reputation as well please feel free to input your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like network bandwidth or latency problems.  Use vSphere client to look at the network topology and make sure that your vcenter NIC is not also used for data traffic.  I'm not sure how much you can see in the free version if you're using that, but using the same physical NIC for vcenter as you use for a high traffic VM will do this.  You can ping the service console or use a scp tool that shows traffic to see if there's latency or bandwidth clogs on the service console nic.

Install a small WinXP VM in your ESXi and load vsphere client.  Can it connect reliably?  If not, you need to know about the network topology to know what that means exactly, but it will rule out the internet as the problem.  If it does disconnect, does it disconnect in lockstep with your local vsphere client?

Answer (score 0):

The console connection is very bandwidth intensive so I'm not surprised you are having slowness issues with that.  Our console connection is currently a 1GB connection but when it was 100MB we had some slowness and an occasional disconnect.

I would recommend contacting Joe's Data Center about not being able to establish a secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command
Log into console via ssh run this command
Service mgmt-vmware restart and try to connect via vsphere

Comment: SSH for ESXi is not enabled by default or recommended by VMware.